# How to tell vim to ignore extern "C" brakets while indenting?

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, filetype-c

I have the following in my `.vimrc` to indent the whole file:

```
nnoremap cu gg=G``
```

I have a problem using this in source files that have

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

// code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This makes vim shift all the functions one tab to the right. This makes it inconsistent with my colleagues who don't use vim and it also annoys me. Is there a way to tell vim to ignore these brakets of `extern "C"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal cinoptions=E-s
```

See [`:h cinoptions-values`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cinoptions-values).

Also make sure that `:h 'equalprg'` is set to empty, so the internal Vim formatter is used. If not, see man pages of an external formatter tool whatever it is.

Comment: I added this line to my `.vimrc`, as well as `set equalprg=""` but when I press `c-u`, it still considers the extern C brakets. Do I miss anything?

Comment: @SalahuddinAhmed In vimrc you have to use `set` (not `setlocal`) to change the default setting. Make sure you've read and understood `:h options.txt`

Comment: @SalahuddinAhmed BTW. The right syntax is `set equalprg=` (which is Vim's default anyway). The double-quote stands for a comment mark, so it doesn't hurt (unless it's followed by another option), but it looks strange, to say the least.

Comment: Now it works. Could you please edit the answer to `set` instead of `setlocal` and add `set equalprg=` so that it becomes complete and clear for future viewer. Thanks